# Grafana can't assume IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, grafana, amazon-eks, identity-management

I've created an IAM (IRSA) role for Grafana running in EKS to access CloudWatch metrics:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:somenamespace:cloudwatch",
                    "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/xxxx:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

with policy attached as described here (IAM Policy section): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/grafana/latest/userguide/adding--CloudWatch-manual.html

I have also tried StringEquals with sub only but with no luck.

I've then created a `serviceAccount` in EKS:

```
serviceAccount:
  name: cloudwatch
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/cloudwatch
```

Grafana deployment uses securityContext set to 472:

```
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 472
        runAsGroup: 472
        runAsUser: 472
```

Unfortunately in Datasource configuration I am getting access denied error:

```
1. CloudWatch metrics query failed: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/cloudwatch/1678127715473319080 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/cloudwatch status code: 403, request id: dc2af0f1-0fb8-4c50-9997-da6cebef02fd 2. CloudWatch logs query failed: AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/cloudwatch/1678127715473319080 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/cloudwatch status code: 403, request id: 2391d405-024d-43ab-a2f9-1db72835a472
```

Comment: error indicates you've already assumed the cloudwatch role and now are trying to assume it again.  Is that inline with what you're expecting?

Comment: @erik258 How is that, where I assumed it twice?

Comment: `User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/cloudwatch/1678127715473319080 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/cloudwatch` the assumed role is the thing attempting to assume the very same role.  You *can* allow that in the assume role policy document, but it is distinct from the WebIdentity stuff.  Assuming a role from the same role is typically (but not always) the result of a configuration error

Comment: @erik258 Sorry but doesn't make any sense. I have the same config for other services and they works. Could you please post a link to the relevant official docs explaining your assumptions?

Comment: "User: arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/cloudwatch/1678127715473319080" that corresponds with `arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/cloudwatch`

Comment: @erik258 yeah, you are right. Grafana is assuming this role second time. Removing `Assume Role ARN` from the Datasource config fixed the problem.

Comment: I can't make that into a valid answer very well, but if you want to, I think you'd be justified in this case

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you configured the Cloudwatch datasource in Grafana, so I'll share from my use case.

#### Background

Going over the following Grafana docs:

1. [Amazon CloudWatch data source](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/)
2. [Configure AWS authentication](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/aws-authentication/#use-eks-iam-roles-for-service-accounts)

I created the role like you did (Ref #1 above) and then added this setup ([Using AWS SDK Default and ARN of IAM Role to Assume](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/aws-cloudwatch/#using-aws-sdk-default-and-arn-of-iam-role-to-assume)) from Ref #2 above) to the Grafana chart:

```
datasources:
  - name: CloudWatch
    type: cloudwatch
    jsonData:
      authType: default
      assumeRoleArn: <the-role-arn>
      defaultRegion: eu-west-2
```

And then I've got the `is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole` error you showed.

#### What solved the issue?

Removing the `assumeRoleArn` line and let Grafana code count on the default AWS Credentials chain.

---

#### In more depth

From [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials):

The AWS SDK for Go requires credentials (an access key and secret access key) to sign requests to AWS. You can specify your credentials in several different locations, depending on your particular use case. For information about obtaining credentials, see Setting Up.

When you initialize a new service client without providing any credential arguments, the SDK uses the default credential provider chain to find AWS credentials.

The SDK uses the first provider in the chain that returns credentials without an error. The default provider chain looks for credentials in the following order:

1. Environment variables.
2. Shared credentials file.
3. If your application uses an ECS task definition or RunTask API operation, IAM role for tasks.
4. If your application is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, IAM role for Amazon EC2.

In our case we're using EKS and the [IRSA](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/) setup which is the equivalent to (3).

---

More references:

1. [CredChain in AWS Go SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/aws/defaults/#).
2. [Enable more complete credential chain for SigV4 default SDK auth option](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/29065).
3. [CloudWatch access with sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity broken in 7.3.x](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/29017)